# Display ajax load with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the latest version of jQuery

i want to display ajax-load/progress image while jquery doing the request and after request complete i want to hide that.

So i may hide that on .success event, but on which event i may display that?

```
 $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })

     //where to display progress?

    .success(function() {  //hide progress })
    .error(function() { //hide progress })
    .complete(function() {  //hide progress });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can display progress just before the ajax call.

```
 // display progress

 $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })

     //where to display progress?

    .success(function() {  //hide progress })
    .error(function() { //hide progress })
    .complete(function() {  //hide progress });
```

Or you can register it in [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart):

```
$('.log').ajaxStart(function() {
  // display progress
});
```

This way, anytime some ajax call begins, you don't have to manually display progress.
Extending that, you can hide that automatically too using [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop) or [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete):

```
$('.log').ajaxStop(function() {
  // hide progress
});
```

Comment: so yes, but there is no such event like beforeRequest or something?

Comment: I use ajax alot and never heard of .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop.  They are quite useful. does this only need to be called once in document.ready?

Comment: @Johnny: Yes. You need to set them up only once.

Comment: It could be the element (`div` e.g.) that display progress.

Answer (score 1):

Do it before you make the AJAX request:

```
function MakeRequest() {
    $('#progress').show();
    $.ajax(...)
        .success(function() { $('#progress').hide(); })
        .error(function() { $('#progress').hide(); })
        .complete(function() { $('#progress').hide(); });
}
```

If you're looking to actually report progress (10%, 20%, etc.) then you will have to rethink this, as this setup will take you from 0 to 100 with no real "progress" getting reported at all. This type of setup is fine for a spinner or a loading message, but that's about it.

Looking through the jQuery docs, there *is* a `beforeSend` event that is local to the request. You can use it like so:

```
 $.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
     // Handle the beforeSend event
     // Show progress
   },
   complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
     // Hide progress
   }
   // ......
 });
```